# Why doesn't this buoyant free energy device work?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, fluid-statics, buoyancy, perpetual-motion

Okay so I've seen a few of these but the setup here is a bit different.

1. Suppose we set up an electrolysis plant at the bottom of the ocean and for some constant energy cost $E_1$, we can get a bunch of pure $H_2$ and $O_2$ (ignoring some inconveniences here like chlorine gas, being at the bottom of the ocean, etc).
2. Suppose we use this highly buoyant gas to lift some balloon like object creating a lifting force $f$ which travels an arbitrary distance $d$ (10km if you want...) for a total of $fd$ work.
3. A powerplant at the surface to recover some fraction of the initial cost $C_1E_1$ by burning hydrogen and oxygen back into water.

So the total energy cost for this system per run would be:
$$(1-C_1)E_1 -fd$$

And since $d$ is arbitrarily large, for an ocean of depth $d$ we would hit breakeven and profit at:
$$d>\frac{(1-C_1)E_1}{f}$$

FURTHERMORE, because the mixure of $H_2$ and $O_2$ is lighter than air (0.09 g/L and 1.4 g/L vs 1.3 g/L when you average, also twice as much hydrogen as oxygen), theoretically we can use a hindenberg to carry a huge block of concrete high into the stratosphere for an additional $mgh$ amount of potential energy. I won't make any claims about how to convert that energy into usable energy, <strike>but it is there and left as an exercise for the reader.</strike>

It seems to me that we are extracting energy from the existing potential energy of water not from the bottom or something but I need a second opinion on this. Would it work or nah?

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as most buoyancy-related perpetual motion schemes: You neglected to include the energy cost of moving the pressurized liquid aside. Here, you didn't account for the work needed to move the ocean out of the way when you dissociated water into its constituent gases. This work, which necessitates extra electrical energy input, scales up with increasing depth, so it's of no use to increase the depth to pay for inefficiencies.

Comment: Is it really so significant? Consider the case where we inflate a hydrogen balloon at sea level, the cost is zero. The maximum height of a hydrogen balloon would be like 20-40km but let's say 20 to be safe. The total mass we could carry would be the density gradient of hydrogen to atmosphere so it would be 1.29 kg/m^3 to 0. Integrating we get 12.9 kg *km/m^3 of hydrogen if we constantly reduce the mass of the balloon as we go up. Unfortunately it seems its like 35 watt hours per m^3 of $H_2$ so that's pretty doomed.

Comment: Compressing this new question into the character limit of a comment renders it indecipherable to me, I’m afraid. I don’t follow the context or assumptions you’re making regarding costs, energy retrieval, or practicality.